# can't use makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am totally new to Reactjs and material UI so
I am getting a lots errors in the makeStyles() can anyone help me with code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      display: "flex",
    },
  },
}));

const Navbar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>

      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            XcitEducation
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
            {/*<div>*/}
            <Button color="inherit" sx={{ mr: 2 }} component={Link} to="/">
              Home
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
              component={Link}
              to="/contact"
            >
              Contact
            </Button>
            <Button color="inherit" sx={{ mr: 2 }} component={Link} to="/about">
              About Us
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }}
              color="success"
              endIcon={<LoginIcon fontSize="small" />}
              component={Link}
              to="/login"
            >
              Login
            </Button>
            <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-menu">
              {(popupState) => (
                <>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="error"
                    {...bindTrigger(popupState)}
                    endIcon={<ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />}
                  >
                    Register
                  </Button>
                  <Menu {...bindMenu(popupState)}>
                    <MenuItem
                      onClick={popupState.close}
                      component={Link}
                      to="/register/StudentReg"
                    >
                      Student
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      onClick={popupState.close}
                      component={Link}
                      to="/register/CompanyReg"
                    >
                      Company
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      onClick={popupState.close}
                      component={Link}
                      to="/login/MyApplicationCard"
                    >
                      My Application
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                </>
              )}
            </PopupState>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

errors I am getting:

1)MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.

2)Navbar.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')

3)Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<div>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might have your App.tsx set up wrong somehow, do you have ThemeProvider in use at all?

Here's an example from a project of mine, not all elements might be applicable to you, but ThemeProvider certainly is (render function from App.tsx):

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  const theme = createTheme({
    // common styles go here
  });
  return (
    <Provider {...this.rootStore}>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/admin">
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <RenderRoutes />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Your NavBar should replace my RenderRoutes object for it to work.
Having ThemeProvider set up properly should solve issues 1 and 2. 3 seems pretty self-explanatory - if you have div inside p tag somewhere then rewrite that.